# When must we use checked operator in C#?

Tags: c#, operators, checked

When must we use `checked` operator in C#?
Is it only suitable for exception handling?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You would use `checked`to guard against a (silent) overflow in an expression.
And use `unchecked` when you know a harmless overflow might occur.

You use both at places where you don't want to rely on the default (project-wide) compiler setting.

Both forms are pretty rare, but when doing critical integer arithmetic it is worth thinking about possible overflow.

Also note that they come in two forms:

```
 x = unchecked(x + 1);    // ( expression )
 unchecked { x = x + 1;}  // { statement(s) }
```

Answer (score 6):

`checked` will help you to pick up **`System.OverFlowException`** which will go unnoticed otherwise

```
int result = checked (1000000 * 10000000);   
    // Error: operation > overflows at compile time

int result = unchecked (1000000 * 10000000);  
    // No problems, compiles fine
```

Answer (score 3):

From [The checked and unchecked operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691349(VS.71).aspx)

> The checked and unchecked operators
>   are used to control the overflow
>   checking context for integral-type
>   arithmetic operations and conversions.
>
> In a checked context, if an expression
>   produces a value that is outside the
>   range of the destination type, the
>   result depends on whether the
>   expression is constant or
>   non-constant. Constant expressions
>   cause compile time errors, while
>   non-constant expressions are evaluated
>   at run time and raise exceptions.
>
> In an unchecked context, if an
>   expression produces a value that is
>   outside the range of the destination
>   type, the result is truncated.

[checked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw(VS.71).aspx), [unchecked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8(VS.71).aspx)

Comment: OK, that's what they are.. Could you elaborate on when you want to do it?

Answer (score 3):

`checked` vs. `unchecked` is also useful in those times when you are doing integer math. especially incrementing operations and you know you will increment past `UInt32.MaxValue`, and want it to harmlessly overflow back to `0`.