# Why does Int32.MaxValue * Int32.MaxValue == 1?

Tags: c#, math, int

I know, `Int32.MaxValue * Int32.MaxValue` will yield a number larger than `Int32`; But, shouldn't this statement raise some kind of an exception?

I ran across this when doing something like `IF (X * Y > Z)` where all are `Int32`. `X` and `Y` are sufficiently large enough, you get a bogus value from `X * Y`.

Why is this so and how to get around this? besides casting everything to `Int64`.

Comment: Is this in an `unchecked` block?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363838/when-must-we-use-checked-operator-in-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have disabled the overflow checks in your project. With checked mode On it will throw an exception.

Comment: thank you for your responses!

I did not disable the overflow check; where is this setting in Visual Studio ?

Comment: I'don't have a copy of VS here but if I remember well it's in the Advanced compiler options (Right click on a project and then Properties -> Build -> Advanced)

Answer (score 26):

Because int32 confines the results to 32bits.

So, if you have a look at the math at a byte level.

```
FFFFFFFF * FFFFFFFF = FFFFFFFE00000001
```

As you can see, the lowest 4 bytes = 1.

Answer (score 19):

By default, C# arithmetic is done in an unchecked context, meaning values will roll over.

You can use the [checked and unchecked keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/khy08726%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) to control that behavior.

Comment: Just ran into a scenario where int.maxvalue + 1 was int.minvalue...I was scratching my head so hard with that one until realized it must be rolling over!

Answer (score 8):

It's interesting to note that this works regardless of the base you use:

```
(n-1)*(n-1)  mod n 
n^2 - 2n + 1 mod n
0   -  0 + 1 mod n
           1 mod n
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to ask for it:

```
checked {
    int a = int.MaxValue;
    int b = int.MaxValue;
    int c = a * b;    // kaboom
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Int32.MaxValue (using the value given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94591/what-is-the-maximum-value-for-a-int32)) is 2,147,483,647.

In base 2, that is: `111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111`... 2^31-1.  The first bit is the sign bit.

If you multiply that by itself, you get: `11 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001`

Going back to the original problem of "why is it 1?", since Integer.MaxValue is the maximum value, that causes an integer overflow.  The result is truncated to the lowest 31 bits, which is all 0s plus 1.

Edit: Here is [a tutorial](http://meseec.ce.rit.edu/eecc341-winter2001/341-12-6-2001.pdf) on binary multiplication.  Using a simple case of all 1s:
111
* 111

you get:
00111
01110
+ 11100
= 100001

You can expand this for the case of Int32.MaxValue.  I shortened it to 3 digits for brevity.

Also, as another answer said, in C# these overflows will occur by default.

Comment: A good treatment for thous who need it, but the OP was wondering why C# didn't catch it and throw an error.